# Can a closed form for the following recurrence relation be found?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fractions

I stumbled across a problem that involves the following recurrence relation (also with different values for the $\frac{2}{3}$):

$$
p(x+1) = p(x) + \frac{2} {3p(x)}\\
\text {or in alternate form}\\
p(x+1) =\frac{p(x)^2 +\frac2 3}{p(x)}
$$

I have no problem finding closed form for the normal linear recurrence relations, but for one that includes fractions like this one does I don't even have a clue where to start.

Comment: Where did this show up? What is the initial value ($p(0)$)?

Comment: Very few non-linear recurrences have closed solutions. By plotting some values and fooling around with some parameters it looks like around 100 to 500 it is closely represented by $p(n) = 0.5 n^{1/3} \ln n + 1$.

Comment: $p(0)=0$ and $p(1)=\frac{2}{3}$. This showed up in a simulation of a chance based growth system with the growth chance being based on how big it already is.

Comment: For very large $x$, approximate by a differential equation?